# Как получить длительность видео, которое находится по ссылке *.m3u8

Tags: python, потоки-данных, видео, m3u

Ссылка формата *.m3u8
Необходимо получить длительность видеоролика без его скачивания (желательно посредствами python)

Comment: [m3u](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) — это **список** ссылок. так что ваш вопрос в текущей формулировке просто лишён смысла и требует переформулировки/конкретизации. для внесения исправлений нажмите [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin так по этим ссылкам может же находиться видеофайл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Проблема решалась благодаря **ffmpeg**:

```
ffmpeg -i '*.m3u8' -f ffmetadata metadata.txt
```

где * - произвольная ссылка, содержащая m3u8 файл.